# What Vertex AI Model is best for large amounts of JSON data in the form key: value

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm looking to use Vertex AI for predictions using sports data.  I have access to enormous amounts of sports data in JSON format.  My question is as a new Vertex user, which model is best to use to train on this type of data?  Text, Tabular etc?  I'm really struggling with the basics and could do with some guidance.  #google-vertex-ai

I havent tried it yet as dont know where to start

Comment: It's not a question of tool, but a question of method. It's a data science question. And you will process data to train your model. The most easiest data format to handle is the tabular format. You have a static schema as model input and you can use a lot of models out of the box. Therefore, I can only recommend you to store the JSON data in a tabular format (BigQuery is the easiest), prepare your data (if you need to have a universal schema, or to perform feature engineering).

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments and advice @guillaumeblaquiere.  I've started down that route as it did seem the most appropriate but I was beginning to doubt myself.  I just need to find some decent training materials around build the data sets for the Vertex Tabular model and then I can get schema design sorted and start joining up my JSON source with the data set uploads and subsequent training.  Think I have much to learn as Vertex seems a pretty complex toolset.